# The difference between s.click("image.png") and s.click("image.png",0)

Tags: automation, sikuli

As stated in the title, using Sikuli, what is the functional difference between `s.click("image.png")` and `s.click("image.png",0)`?

I haven't been able to find anything about this modifier in the documentation and haven't noticed any functional difference in my Java scripts using one or the other.

I ask because I see the extra `,0` used in other's scripts constantly, but do not understand why.

Are there other modifiers people use instead of `,0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of the zero acts as a clear indication there are no acting modifiers.

Possible modifiers for `click(PSRML target, int modifiers)`:

> Can be 0 (no modifier), K_SHIFT, K_CTRL, K_ALT or K_META

I found the answer in [this documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Region.html#click(PSRML,%20int)), and [here is more information](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html) on available modifiers.

Comment: Oh, alright. So essentially, `click("image",K_SHIFT)` would be the equivalent of a shift-click, if I'm thinking correctly?

Comment: I believe so! I saw a (barely) related question on SO about using a ["Ctrl+C" keyboard entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337629/how-to-send-ctrl-c-in-sikuli) which may help you. Unfortunately my only experience with Sikuli is looking up documentation for your question. :) I've edited my comment to include the documentation for Sikuli modifiers.